# Can I return a ViewBag property to Ajax success callback?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am calling an MVC controller from ajax. The controller is supposed to return a ViewBag property called Counter:

```
public ActionResult GetSomething()
{
    var someModel = ...

    ViewBag.Counter = 5;

    return PartialView("SomePartialView", someModel);
}
```

I call the controller via ajax. What I want is to get access to the ViewBag property called Counter inside the ajax success callback. Is this possible?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/GetSomething",
    content: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
       // How can I access Counter from here
    },
});
```

PS: Returning Counter in a model from the controller is not an option. Is must be in a ViewBag.

UPDATE:

Updated the controller with a return value, to let you know, that I cannot return the Counter in a Json.

**Solution:**

I ended up rewriting my controller like this:

```
public JsonResult GetHeaderBasketPreview()
{
    var someModel = ...

    return Json(new { pViewHtml = HtmlHelpers.RenderViewToString(this.ControllerContext, "SomePartialView", someModel), counter = 5 });
}
```

It now returns the html for my partial, plus my counter variable.

RenderViewToString looks like this (I found this helper method in an answer on stackoverflow - but don't remember where):

```
public static string RenderViewToString(ControllerContext context, string viewName, object model)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
        viewName = context.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

    var viewData = new ViewDataDictionary(model);

    using (var sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(context, viewName);
        var viewContext = new ViewContext(context, viewResult.View, viewData, new TempDataDictionary(), sw);
        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

        return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
}
```

I can now access both variables in my ajax success callback:

```
success: function (data, status, xhr) {
    $('#somePartialView').html(data.pViewHtml);
    $('#counterIndicator').html(data.counter);
}
```

Comment: No. Just use `return Json(5);` and the value of `date` will be 5

Comment: you want to use the ViewBag.Counter in returned Partial View ?

Comment: No, I need the ViewBag.Counter for something outside the Partial View.

Comment: @brinch - Okay. Then may be set counter value in hidden field in Partial View and access that in ajax success .

Comment: @brinch, Make 2 ajax calls if necessary - one to return the partial and one for the value. Or put the value in a hidden input and read it from the input when you add it to the DOM.

Comment: You are returning the partial view. so in your $.ajax, dataType: "json", should be dataType: "html". And also as Stephen suggested, create an hidden html in your partial view and access it in your success function after adding the returned html to your page

Answer (score 4):

That's not a possibility as the data parameter is simply a string of HTML which is generated when you do `PartialView("SomePartialView", someModel)`

One option is the following:

Within your controller action add `Response.Headers["Counter"] = 5`

Within your ajax.success, take in two extra parameters `status` and `xhr` so that your success function looks like this:

`success: function (data, status, xhr) {`

After this you can use `xhr.getResponseHeader("Counter")` which will give you `5` (or whatever you choose to pass in)

Answer (score 3):

Please use your return syntax from your action like this way ...

```
return Json(new { success = ViewBag.Counter }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Get the response on your view like this ...

```
success: function (data) {
                     alert(data.success); 
                       },
```

Comment: you can also pass your counter value directly instead of ViewBag.Counter.

Comment: @brinch - you can pass the counter with the model to partial view .

Comment: @Ajinder: No that's not an option, as I'm going to use the Counter outside the partial view.

Comment: you just now changed your question, i will provide you an answer plz wait

Comment: you have to change your return type if you want to access some thing in ajax success.